# Unable to integrate sentry with Springboot Webflux

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, sentry

I'm encountering an issue with my Spring WebFlux application where I'm using the Sentry library for error tracking. However, I'm facing the following error, and I'm not sure how to resolve it:

my file `application.yml`:

```yaml
    sentry:
      dsn: 
      traces-sample-rate: 1.0
      debug: true
      sample-rate: 1
      exception-resolver-order: -2147483647
      tracing-origins: localhost,^(http|https)://api\\..*$
      environment: production
```

File `pom.xml`:

```xml
    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
            <artifactId>sam-doma-con</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <name>sample project</name>
            <description>Spring Boot </description>
        
            <properties>
                <java.version>1.8</java.version>
                <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
                <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
                <log4j2.version>2.16.0</log4j2.version>
                <springfox-version>3.0.0</springfox-version>
            </properties>
    <dependencies>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    <dependency>
                <groupId>io.sentry</groupId>
                <artifactId>sentry-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                <version>6.28.0</version>
            </dependency>
       </dependencies>
```

here is my trace

```java
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpResponse.getRawStatusCode()Ljava/lang/Integer;
        at io.sentry.spring.webflux.SentryWebFilter.finishTransaction(SentryWebFilter.java:149) ~[sentry-spring-6.28.0.jar:na]
        at io.sentry.spring.webflux.SentryWebFilter.lambda$filter$0(SentryWebFilter.java:79) ~[sentry-spring-6.28.0.jar:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoFinally$DoFinallySubscriber.runFinally(FluxDoFinally.java:156) ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoFinally$DoFinallySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDoFinally.java:139) ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onComplete(FluxOnAssembly.java:395) ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onComplete(MonoPeekTerminal.java:292) ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onComplete(MonoPeekTerminal.java:292) ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onComplete(FluxOnAssembly.java:395) ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onComplete(MonoPeekTerminal.java:292) ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onComplete(MonoPeekTerminal.java:292) ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onComplete(FluxOnAssembly.java:395) ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:189) ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:260) ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onComplete(Operators.java:1871) ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onComplete(FluxOnAssembly.java:395) ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:189) ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:260) ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onComplete(MonoPeekTerminal.java:292) ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ChannelSendOperator$WriteCompletionBarrier.onComplete(ChannelSendOperator.java:423) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreElements$IgnoreElementsSubscriber.onComplete(MonoIgnoreElements.java:81) ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.onComplete(FluxConcatArray.java:191) ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.onComplete(Operators.java:1679) ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenAcceptInner.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:314) ~[reactor-core-3.3.2.RELEASE.jar:3.3.2.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.channel.MonoSendMany$SendManyInner.run(MonoSendMany.java:320) [reactor-netty-0.9.4.RELEASE.jar:0.9.4.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.channel.MonoSendMany$SendManyInner.trySchedule(MonoSendMany.java:383) [reactor-netty-0.9.4.RELEASE.jar:0.9.4.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.channel.MonoSendMany$SendManyInner.trySuccess(MonoSendMany.java:527) [reactor-netty-0.9.4.RELEASE.jar:0.9.4.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.channel.MonoSendMany$SendManyInner.trySuccess(MonoSendMany.java:94) [reactor-netty-0.9.4.RELEASE.jar:0.9.4.RELEASE]
        at io.netty.util.internal.PromiseNotificationUtil.trySuccess(PromiseNotificationUtil.java:48) [netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.safeSuccess(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:717) [netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.remove(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:272) [netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.removeBytes(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:352) [netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doWrite(NioSocketChannel.java:414) [netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:930) [netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.flush0(AbstractNioChannel.java:354) [netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:897) [netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1372) [netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:748) [netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:740) [netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:726) [netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.flush(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:531) [netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.flush(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:125) [netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.flush(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:356) [netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:748) [netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:740) [netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:726) [netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at reactor.netty.channel.MonoSendMany$SendManyInner$AsyncFlush.run(MonoSendMany.java:633) [reactor-netty-0.9.4.RELEASE.jar:0.9.4.RELEASE]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute$$$capture(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164) [netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java) [netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472) [netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500) [netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) [netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) [netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) [netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar:4.1.45.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [na:1.8.0_362-362]
```

I suspect that this error is related to compatibility issues between the Sentry library and Spring WebFlux. I've tried checking the documentation and performing some troubleshooting, but I'm still stuck.

Here's what I've tried so far:

Verified my library versions to ensure they are compatible.
Reviewed my project's build configuration to eliminate any conflicting dependencies.
Checked for any additional error messages or warnings in the stack trace.
However, I'm not sure what exactly is causing this issue and how to proceed with resolving it. Has anyone else encountered a similar problem? Are there any specific configurations or steps I need to take to make Sentry and Spring WebFlux work together without issues?

If anyone has insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` related to the `ServerHttpResponse.getRawStatusCode()` method, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Did you verify that the method actually exists? I.e., a lib with that class+method is in the classpath, and there is no other copy of the class exists? note that class can be inside any jar, sometimes some libs put some 3rd party classes into their jar and that causes such conflicts

Answer (score 0):

In what context does this error occur? When running from the IDE, or when executing the jar? In either case it looks like your dependencies are not packaged into the executable.

I wasn't able to reproduce your error, but here is a modified version of your `pom.xml` that worked for me.

The differences to your example are:

- added the spring boot starter parent (provides default configuration, also the spring boot version needs to be specified only once)
- added the spring boot maven plugin (responsible for packaging all necessary libraries into an executable jar)

pom.xml:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.5</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<groupId>com.sample</groupId>
<artifactId>sam-doma-con</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<name>sample project</name>
<description>Spring Boot </description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    <log4j2.version>2.16.0</log4j2.version>
    <springfox-version>3.0.0</springfox-version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.sentry</groupId>
        <artifactId>sentry-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>6.28.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Hope this helps.